# UPS power calculation

Tags: ups

I calculate [here](http://www.coolermaster.com/power-supply-calculator/) 420 watt for my system unit, also monitor needs 45 watt. If I get UPS with active power 500+ watt, would it be enough? My current power supply is for 600 watt. Or better to buy UPS with 600+ watt active power?

Comment: You'll need to know current demand on all buses, e.g. 12 V, 5 V, etc. If any *one* exceeds the current capability of the supply, it will not work. Simply assuming total power is the same is not enough.

Comment: IMO there is no "on-paper" calculation that substitutes for an actual external "usage monitor" measurement (e.g. a Kill-a-Watt meter).  FWIW a desktop PC measures about 25 watts at idle and about 90 watts at 100% load compiling software.  It has a 350W PSU, and that online "wattage calculator" estimates that this system uses 279 watts,You can guesstimate on paper, or make an actual measurement.